# Как tar вылавливает все хардлинки файлов?

Tags: unix, файловая-система, tar

Как tar вылавливает все хардлинки затариваемых файлов? (Он добавляет их список в заголовок каждого файла в архиве...)

По номеру иноды - неоднозначно, может быть задана иерархия, включающая в себя несколько файловых систем разом и номера инод могут перекрываться.
А он не ошибается...

Comment: *Предложение садиться вычитывать исходники за ответ не считается* — ну да, логично. кто-то это должен сделать **за вас**.

Comment: Мой вопрос задан тем, кто знает ответ, а не тем, кто пойдет с нуля разбираться вместо меня. Полагаю, что ответы типа "читай документацию" и "читай исходники" - не ответ, а банальное хамство. Они ничего не дают спрашивающему - несомненно он и сам знает эти сентенции. Но, раз он решил спросить, значит у него были для этого основания. Иначе - эакройте это проект и напишите всего две фразы: "читай документацию" и "читай исходники".

Comment: всё-таки настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с правилами данного ресурса. тогда, надеюсь, вы поймёте всю неуместность как вашего требования, так и вашего возмущения. разжевываю: на этом ресурсе ответы в описанном вами духе (rtfm и т.п.) живут, как правило, несколько минут (ну, может, часов).

Answer (score 0):

если заглянуть в [исходники](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/create.c#n1451), можно обнаружить такую функцию сравнения:

```
/* Compare two links for equality.  */
static bool
compare_links (void const *entry1, void const *entry2)
{
  struct link const *link1 = entry1;
  struct link const *link2 = entry2;
  return ((link1->dev ^ link2->dev) | (link1->ino ^ link2->ino)) == 0;
}
```

и даже не заглядывая в описание структуры `link`, догадаться, что сравниваются не только `inode` файла, **но и идентификатор устройства** `dev`, на котором файл располагается.